# How to train a multi inputs deep learning model using every combination of inputs?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I am beginner in deep learning. I want to create a multi inputs CNN model in Keras. The model takes two inputs of images to give the two images class. The 
two images from differnt datasets that have the same classes exactly.

During training, I want to try every combination of the two images if the images are from the **same class**.

I created used multi input one output model, but I could not create a custom fit_generator function.

How can I make a generator that try every combination of the two images if the images are from the same class ??

Please help me. Please help me.

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1627